# How to get user auth info in FastAPI, when using `app.add_route()` for GraphQL?

Tags: python, oauth, graphql, fastapi, starlette

I'm using FastAPI and now want to add GraphQL using `graphene`.

I'm using:

- `fastapi-user`
- `starlette.graphql.GraphQLApp`

Here's the routing for GraphQL and how I used fastapi-user package.

```py
import fastapi_users
from starlette.graphql import GraphQLApp
from mypackage.schema import my_schema
...

app.include_router(fastapi_users.router, prefix="/users", tags=["users"])
app.include_router(google_oauth_router, prefix="/google-oauth", tags=["users"])
app.add_route("/", GraphQLApp(schema=my_schema))
...
```

In the `schema`, I need to get user information and control the role based auth.

How to, or how can I use `get_current_active_user()` method with GraphQL schema?

Comment: So ummm, help me understand the question better--you need context of the request and if you have that-- then you can use info.context.user in a middleware to implement RBAC. Do I understand it correctly? And if I do-- let me know if you need more help with it.

Comment: @frozenOne That's what I wanted. You've pointed the exact issue. Wish your answer.

Comment: Use an authorization middleware as mentioned here https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/middleware/

It'll execute before the it hits the controller, place it after the authentication middleware. And before calling resolve, do the authorization logic right there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `my_schema` inherits `graphene.ObjectType` and that the first argument is `info` as shown in the example at:

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/graphql/

```
from graphene import ObjectType, String

class Query(ObjectType):
    hello = String(name=String(default_value="stranger"))

    def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
        return "Hello " + name
```

`info` contains the session object with your user information.

`info.context['request'].session['user']`